# Relation between $L^1(T)$ and $L^1[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I know the question may be too general, but I need to know if there is a way in which I could relate the spaces $L^1(T)$ (where $T=\{e^{2 \pi i x}: x \in [0,1]\}$ and we use the Lebesgue measure on the borelians of $T$) and the usual space $L^1[0,1]$, for instance, by means of a direct sum or something like that. I know for example that I can define the relation $S: L^1(T) \to L^1[0,1]$:
$$
Sf(x):=f \circ e^{2 \pi ix}
$$

But I have difficulties to get a richer relation from this. Any help would be welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your map S is an isometric isomorphism.  Basically they're the same space.

Comment: There's no real difference between $L^{1}(T)$ and $L^{1}[0,1]$. Every function $f \in L^{1}[0,1]$ can be written as $f(x)=g(e^{2\pi i x})$ for a unique $g \in L^{1}(T)$, and every $g\in L^{1}(T)$ gives rise to $f(x)=g(e^{2\pi ix})$ in $L^{1}[0,1]$. This map is a linear isometric isomorphism.

Comment: @T.A.E. That's an answer, right?

Comment: @T.A.E. thanks for your answer. could you give such unique $g\in L^1(T)$?

Comment: Sure, but remember that elements of $L^{1}(T)$, $L^{1}[0,1]$ are equivalence classes of functions which are equal a.e. to each other. Define $g(z)=f(\mbox{log}(z)/2\pi i)$ where log is the branch with $\Im(\mbox{log}(z)) \in [0,2\pi)$.